# how to retrieve message_id for a mail using deliver_later(sidekiq)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer, sidekiq, messageid

I want the SMTP message_id of a mail using deliver_later(sidekiq).

I am able to get the id in the return obj of deliver_now but not deliver_later.

Message_id is also missing in the return value of mail() function inside my_action_mailer

- when I send mail using-

`sent_mail = some_mail().deliver_later`

the response is a sidekiq job object which looks like this-

```
#<ActionMailer::DeliveryJob:0x007fefa1454780 @arguments=["xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "deliver_now", xxxxxxx], @job_id="69b13253-55f9-4db9-a10a-0e8e4b998584", @queue_name="mailers", @priority=nil, @executions=0, @provider_job_id="6f75131d0c485534322cd728">
```

- when I send the mail using -

`sent_mail = some_mail().deliver_now`

the response is a object object which looks like this-

```
<Mail::Message:xx, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: xx>, <From: "xx" <xx@xx.com>>, <Reply-To: "xx" <xx@xx.com>>, <To: ["xx@xx.com"]>, <Message-ID: <5a7863381167a_ba183fdfebc3f928907cb@xx-xx-xx.xx.mail>>, <Subject: xx>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="--==_mimepart_xx"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>>
```

If you'll look closely at the above output, the return class is **Mail::Message** and it contains "**Message-ID**", which is what I need.

- Also, when we call mail() function inside my mailer class, it also returns  **Mail::Message** object but this obj dosent not contains Message-ID returned from SMTP server.

Is there any way in which I can get a Message-ID with using **deliver_later**

Comment: can u post some lines ?

Comment: post yr codes, and error log

Answer (score 1):

### This is the standard way of handling this case:

Overwrite `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob`, something like this:

```rb
class EmailDeliveryJob < ActionMailer::DeliveryJob
  def perform(mailer, mail_method, delivery_method, *args)
    response = mailer.constantize.public_send(mail_method, *args).send(delivery_method)

    # Use response.message_id as you want
  end
end
```

In your mailer,

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.delivery_job = EmailDeliveryJob

  def welcome_email(user)
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Welcome!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I decided to use Mailgun HTTPS API instead, but inside a Sidekiq Job.

So I call the job `MailgunJob.perform_later(stuff_to_send)`

And in the job

```rb
response = RestClient.post "https://mailgun_path", data
result = JSON.parse(response.body)
message_id = result['id']
```

Could you maybe use a job, and **inside** the job use `deliver_now`?

If you have found a better solution, can you write it here?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use an [ActionMailer observer](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Observing+and+Intercepting+Mails).

First, add the record id to your mailer message with a header or the `#metadata` attribute:

```
class YourMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def your_email(record)
    self.message['X-Your-Record-Id'] = record.id
    # or metadata['record_id'] = record.id

    ...
  end
end
```

Create an observer:

```
# app/models/custom_observer.rb

class CustomObserver
  def self.delivered_email(m)
    return unless m.delivered?

    # Access m.message_id or any header you want e.g. m['X-Your-Record-Id']
    Record.find(m['X-Your-Record-Id'].to_s).update_column(:message_id, m.message_id)
  end
end
```

Register the observer:

```
# config/initializers/action_mailer.rb

ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(CustomObserver)
```

And you're good to go. This works with `#deliver` and `#deliver_later` compared to creating a custom `ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob` (which only works with `#deliver_later`).